# Flutter - create textfield that grows when swipe up like slack app

Tags: android, flutter, widget, textfield

I want to create custom widget like slack app in flutter, since there is no pre built widget in flutter, I don't understand how to create that.
I tried to create using combination of bottom sheet and textfield.

Please see the gif:
[[[Screenahot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmZZO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruUOB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px3da.jpg)

I have tried to create widget using bottom sheet and textfield. But i could not create

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  double _sheetHeight = 50.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Swipeable TextField'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
          
          setState(() {
            _sheetHeight -= details.primaryDelta!;
            if (_sheetHeight < 50.0) {
              _sheetHeight = 50.0;
            }
          });
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  reverse: true,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                     
                      _buildPreviousMessages(),

                      _buildExpandingTextField(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPreviousMessages() {
   
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text('Previous messages go here...'),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildExpandingTextField() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      height: _sheetHeight,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: TextField(
        controller: _textEditingController,
        maxLines: null, 
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: 'Type your message...',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.